# Django Slug Not Working In get_absolute_url

Tags: django, django-urls

Whats wrong with this code? `get_absolute_url` is blank when rendered in my template, which means It's failing somewhere.

I suspect it's the slug as this is the first time I have tried to use it within Django:

Thanks

**Model:**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse("EntryDetail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

**URL:**

```
 url(r'^entry/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html',
                           blog_views.EntryDetail.as_view(),
                           name='blog_entry'),
```

**View:**

```
class EntryDetail(DetailView):

    context_object_name = 'entry'
    template_name = "blog.entry.html"
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Entry, url=self.slug_field)
```

Comment: Can you also post your template? I also think you should use the url name and not the view name in the reverse function (but I might be mistaking here).

Comment: Yeah, `reverse` is looking for a view function, not an class.  Use `reverse('blog_entry', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})` and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what @Peter DeGlopper stated in comments: It looks like your trying to get the absolute URL using a **Class Based View**. Don't use **reverse** here, instead you should always give your URLs a name, and then refer to that.

For example this is how it should look:

**model**

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
   return 'blog_entry', (), {'slug': self.slug}
```

**urls**

```
url(r'^entry/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html',
     blog_views.EntryDetail.as_view(),
       name='blog_entry'),
```

Comment: Though this is the accepted answer it is still better to use reverse as permalink is not recommended in django anymore: "The permalink decorator is no longer recommended. You should use reverse() in the body of your get_absolute_url method instead." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator.